# MySQL Trigger to enforce constraint

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a table to enforce the following constraints on my movie table

- The length cannot be less than 30 minutes or more than 480 minutes
- The year must be 1929 or later

Here's my trigger:

```
Create trigger trigger1 before insert on movies
For each row
Begin
    If (year < 1929 or length <30 or length > 480) then
Set message_text = “Invalid Input”’
End If
End
```

Would this be the correct way of enforcing the constraints in this situation? Or should I be doing something else?

Comment: You could also just use a constraint on the creation of the table, or just alter the table and add the constraint to the year and length fields. No need to create a trigger for this type of simple constraint.

Comment: I guess im confused, is there a statement that would tell mysql to abort the insert when it meets certain conditions? Assuming I wanted to use a trigger for the constraint, is this fine?

Comment: Yes if you place the constraints on the table, mysql will make sure the constraints aren't violated on any inserts/updates, and if they are violated, then it will show an error and won't let the insert/update go through.

Comment: @SS781: MySQL does not support check constraints - triggers are the only option here

Answer (score 1):

Check constraints are currently not supported by MySQL.

You are allowed to define one but are silently ignored by the engine.
They are being allowed to define for future support.

You can add an explicit trigger to throw an error state with proper message.

**Example**:

```
signal sqlstate 1062 set message_text = error_message;
```

Change your trigger body as below:

```
Create trigger trigger1 before insert on movies
For each row
Begin
    If (year < 1929 or length <30 or length > 480) then
        Set error_message = 'Invalid Input ';

        signal sqlstate 1062 set message_text = error_message;
    End If;
End
```